# Django and Postgres: Relation Does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, many-to-one

Here is the exact error I am getting:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "blog_blogtype" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."blog_blogtype"."id", "blog_blogtype"."type" FROM "blog_blog...
```

I have created the tables in a database in Postgres but when I try to migrate Django returns this error. My models are below. I created the column referencing to the BlogType model "type" column. I do not know what else to put here. If needed please comment it, so I can add. Thank you in advance.

```
class BlogType(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type


class BlogPost(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_body = models.TextField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(BlogType, related_name="type", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

EDIT: I have found that this line in my views.py is causing the problem. I still cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
blog_post_types =  list(BlogType.objects.all())
```

Comment: How have you `created the tables`? And how exactly you `try to migrate Django`? As in what was the sequence of your actions and what commands did you use? The error shows that the tables are not created in DB so it is essential do show what you did.

Comment: I first created the tables separately in terminal in my database, then I just did `python3 manage.py migrate` @RomanKonoval

Comment: Did you do `python3 manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: @Aurélien yes both commands give a relation error

Comment: Drop database or delete all tables in database. And run migrate again.

Comment: @Ilko so I only keep de database and delete tables and migrate like that?

Comment: @AndrewSerra yes, keep database, only delete tables. When you run `python manage.py migrate`  Django will create tables again.